# Inital value problem, differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I'm asked to solve the problem: $7\frac{dy}{dt}+y= 28t$ with $y(0)=2$

When I integrated I ended up getting $y= (14t^2+C)/(7+t)$, then I plugged in 0 for $t$ and 2 for $y$ to find that $C$ is 14. Leaving my final answer at $y(t)=(14t^2+14)/(7+t)$
But for whatever reason my homework isn't taking it. My assumption would be that I didn't integrate it correctly but I think I did. I subtracted y to the other side then multiplied dt to the other side and integrated both sides leaving me with:
$7y=14t^2-ty+C$

Then I added ty to the other side and factored out $y$ and divided $(7+t)$. Kinda stuck, not sure where I went wrong. Also I apologize for my notation, not too good at using this site.

Comment: Have you learned Integrating Factor?

Answer (score 5):

$7y'+y=28t$ This is a first-order non-homogeneous differential equation.
Fist step is to find the general solution $y_c(t)$
$$7y'+y=0\\7r+1=0\\r=-\frac17$$Therefore $y_c(t)=c_1e^{-\frac17t}$

Now find the particular solution $y_p(t)$: Set $y_p(t)=At+B$

Then,$$y'_p(t)=A\\7A+At+B=28t$$
We get$$7A+B=0,A=28,B=-196$$
Thus $y_p(t)=28t-196$

Finally,$$y(t)=y_c(t)+y_p(t)=c_1e^{\frac17t}+28t-196$$
Plug in the initial value:$$y(0)=c_1-196=2\\c_1=198$$
So$$y(t)=198e^{\frac17t}+28t-196$$

Comment: do you know if your method has a name?

Comment: Undetermined Coefficients

Comment: @Moo, Thank you. I've never seen that :O How does the first passage work? Why did you substitute the derivative with $r$ and $y$ with 1?

Comment: Review - many times: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/UndeterminedCoefficients.aspx

Comment: @Moo, Thank you, I think I should worry if I haven't seen that in my course

Comment: It is typically not used on first order DEs, but works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the integrating factor. In general if you have a differential equation of the form:
\begin{equation}
\frac{dy}{dt} + p(t)y = q(t)
\end{equation}
Where $p(t)$ and $q(t)$ are functions of $t$ only, you can multiply both side by a factor, called integrating factor, which brings the equation to a special form. You'll have an exact derivative on the RHS and then $q(t)I$ on the LHS, where $I$ is the integrating factor.

The integrating factor for linear odes of this type is $I(t) = e^{\int^t{p(\mu)\, d\mu}}$, where $\mu$ is a dummy variable, i.e. is just a place-holder variable, a variable that we use just to be able do to the calculation without confusion.

Once you multiply by this integrating factor, you'll need to integrate both sides, the RHS will be easy by F$\theta$C, the rest will be easy enough with some calculus background.

In your case DON'T FORGET to divide by 7 before applying this concept. The equation must be exactly in the form written above.
So you'll have:
\begin{equation}
\frac{dy}{dt} + \frac{1}{7}y = 4t
\end{equation}
Where your integrating factor will be $I(t) = e^{\int^t{\frac{1}{7}\,d\mu}} =e^{\frac{t}{7}} $, where again $\mu$ is a dummy variable.
By distributivity you'll have then the following
\begin{equation}
e^{\frac{t}{7}}\frac{dy}{dt} + e^{\frac{t}{7}}\frac{1}{7}y = e^{\frac{t}{7}}4t
\end{equation}
Now the interesting thing is that on the RHS you have the above-mentioned exact derivative. Indeed using the standard rule for the derivative of a product you have that

RHS $ = \frac{d}{dt}\left(ye^{\frac{t}{7}}\right)$
I leave the rest to you. Once you'll integrate the LHS, you'll get a constant. You can find the value of this constant by applying the initial condition given.